# Function (int?) that returns pointer in c

Tags: c

I know that i have to define at the beginning of the function what type it is supposed to return, but i dont know how to do it with pointer.. i try to do it like this with int * but its not working

```
int *sorting(int Num_Gaag, FILE *f) {
  typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int size;
    float power;
  } gaag;
  gaag *arrgaags;
  int i = 0, j;
  int counter = 0;

  arrgaags = malloc(sizeof(gaag) * Num_Gaag);
  fseek(f, 67, SEEK_SET);
  for (i = 0; i < Num_Gaag; i++)
    fscanf_s(f, "(%d,%d)   \t%d\t%f\n", &arrgaags[i].x, &arrgaags[i].y,
             &arrgaags[i].size, &arrgaags[i].power);
  return *arrgaags;
}
```

thank you!

Comment: You want return a `int *` or a `gaag *` ? Your [mcve] is very unclear.

Comment: It will be difficult to use a `gaag*` outside of the function if its definition is only visible inside the function, even if you could somehow return it.

Comment: You can't return `arrgaags` if the function returns an `int` or `int *`; `arrgaags` (that sounds like a cry for help!) is a pointer to a structure type that is not accessible outside this function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the structure outside the function, then you can return `gaag*`.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int size;
    float power;
} gaag;

gaag *sorting(int Num_Gaag, FILE *f) {
    gaag *arrgaags;
    int i = 0, j;
    int counter = 0;

    arrgaags = malloc(sizeof(gaag) * Num_Gaag);
    fseek(f, 67, SEEK_SET);
    for (i = 0; i < Num_Gaag; i++)
        fscanf_s(f, "(%d,%d)   \t%d\t%f\n", &arrgaags[i].x, &arrgaags[i].y,
                 &arrgaags[i].size, &arrgaags[i].power);
    return arrgaags;
}
```

Note that you don't use `*` when returning the pointer, since that would return just the structure that the pointer points to (the first element of the array).

Comment: But you don't `free(arrgaags)` it creates a memory leak.

Comment: The caller has to free it when they're done using the array.